# Better way to add dashed border to a path element in an svg

Tags: svg, d3.js

Is there a better solution to add to a path element a dashed border (lets say the border should have an offset of 2px in each direction)
I am looking for a general solution for a lot of path elements

For example my initial path element would be

```
 <path stroke="black" fill="none" d="M10 10 L 50 10 L 50 80 L 10 80 Z"></path>
```

and at the moment I am creating another path element to add the border around the initial path element

```
<path stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="3" fill="none" d="M6 6 L 54 6 L 54 84 L 6 84 Z"></path>
```

```html
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
   <path stroke="black" fill="none" 
         d="M10 10 L 50 10 L 50 80 L 10 80 Z"></path>
   <path stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="3" 
         fill="none" d="M6 6 L 54 6 L 54 84 L 6 84 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Seems like you have a working solution. For any arbitrary path, doing this programatically is going to be very hard though.

Comment: Yeah I have a solution that is working but its quite ugly that I need to create another path element just to add a border-like shape, I was hoping that there would be a better way to do this

Comment: I have corrected the half-baked answer I gave yesterday, now correctly scales

Answer (score 3):

"a general solution for a lot of path elements" is pretty vague. I'll handle simple closed paths in this answer.

This way may actually be more of an example how not to do it, but I think it shows a general problem with what you try to achieve. It uses only one place to define a path, and then re-uses it in three other places:

- first, to draw the inner border,
- then, to draw a much wider dashed border,
- and finally, as a mask to hide that part of the dashed border that would otherwise overlap the inner one.

This has the advantage of not having to create extra paths, but the dashed border looks strange. The corners either show gaps or exta-long dashes, and in curved sections the length of the dashes are differing.

```css
.distance {
    stroke-width: 6;
}
.inner {
    fill:none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
.outer {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke-dasharray: 4;
    stroke-dashoffset: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <path id="src" d="M 32,13 20,42 Q 30,90 85,90 L 92,53 Q 60,53 60,13 Z" />
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <use class="distance" href="#src" stroke="black" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <use class="inner" href="#src" />
  <use class="outer" href="#src" mask="url(#mask)" />
</svg>
```

Why is that so? The dashes are computed in relation to where the original path is, but what is shown is only the outer fringe of the whole stroke, at an offset. (or to put it the other way round, the path defining where dashes start and end is at an offset from the middle of the shown dashed line.) For concave sections, dashes get longer, and for convex sections, shorter.

The only way the dash length can be stable is when the path used to compute dashes sits in the middle of the dashes. You could change the order around and define the dashes on the inner border:

```css
.distance {
    stroke-width: 6;
}
.inner {
    fill:none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-dasharray: 4;
}
.outer {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <path id="src" d="M 32,13 20,42 Q 30,90 85,90 L 92,53 Q 60,53 60,13 Z" />
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <use class="distance" href="#src" stroke="black" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <use class="inner" href="#src" />
  <use class="outer" href="#src" mask="url(#mask)" />
</svg>
```

..but that is as far as you get. The bottom line remains: you need to have a path where the dashed line is, not at an offset.

Answer (score 1):

Use a native JavaScript Web Component `<svg-outline>` (you define once)
to do the work on an `<svg>`

```html
<svg-outline>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"  height="180">
    <path outline="blue" fill="none" d="M5 5 L 50 30 L 50 40 L 10 80 Z"/>
  </svg>
</svg-outline>
```

The Web Component clones your original shapes (marked with "outline" attribute)

- sets a stroke and stroke-dasharray on it
- removes any existing fill
- transforms clone

  - translates clone to account for `scale(1.2)`
  - scales clone to 1.2 size
  - then corrects `translate`

#### SO snippet output:

[image]

See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/2goahcqv/

```html
<svg-outline>
  <style> circle[outline] { stroke: blue } </style>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="180">
    <rect outline="green" x="15" y="15" width="50%" height="50%" stroke="blue" fill="teal"/>
    <circle outline fill="lightcoral" cx="50" cy="50" r="10"/>
  </svg>
</svg-outline>
<svg-outline>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"  height="180">
    <path outline="blue" fill="pink" d="M15 10 L 50 30 L 50 40 L 20 70 Z"/>
  </svg>
</svg-outline>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-outline", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // make sure innerHTML is parsed
        let svg = this.querySelector("svg");
        svg.querySelectorAll('[outline]').forEach(original => {
          let outlined = svg.appendChild(original.cloneNode(true));
          original.after(outlined); // so we don't create "z-index" issues
          let outline_stroke = outlined.getAttribute("outline") || false;
          if (outline_stroke) outlined.setAttribute("stroke", outline_stroke );
          original.removeAttribute("outline"); // so we can use CSS on outlines
          let {x,y,width,height} = original.getBBox(); 
          let cx = x + width/2;
          let cy = y + height/2;
          outlined.setAttribute("fill", "none"); // outlines never filled
          outlined.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", 3); // or read from your own attribute, like "outline"
          outlined.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${cx} ${cy}) scale(${1.2}) translate(-${cx} -${cy})`);
        });
        // (optional) whack everything into shadowDOM so styles don't conflict
        this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}).append(...this.children);
      })
    }
  })
</script>
```